# Cache the Hashtable in MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hashtable

I have a function, simple function from a public class.

That function creates an `Hashtable` object with information given from database, the part of his function like this:

```
try {
            while ( dataReader.Read() ) {
               Hashtable table1= new Hashtable();
               Hashtable table2= new Hashtable();

               table1.Add( dataReader["field1"].ToString(), Localization.English(dataReader["field1"]);

               table2.Add( dataReader["field2"].ToString(), Localization.French(dataReader["field2"]);
            }
         } catch ( Exception e ) {
            Console.WriteLine( e.Message );
         }
```

I want to cache these two `Hashtable`s and use them in other classes. As I know, I cannot use `HttpRuntime.Cache` even if I used `System.Web` namespace.

I saw that `HttpRuntime.Cache` could be used in `Model` class.

Are there other way to cache these `Hashtable`s ?

PS: Sorry if my question is poor.

Comment: Can you elabortate on why you are unsable to use HttpRuntime.Cache?

Comment: `I saw that HttpRuntime.Cache could be used in -Model- class.`

Comment: Additional notes; there is also MemoryCache (or name similar to that) if the web-cache isn't suitable for some reason. Also, `HashTable`: note that all updates must be synchronized (although reads do **not** need to be synchronized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two projects , like a Models or Entities project and your web project all you need to do is add a reference in the Models project to System.Web. If you did not add a reference to System.Web then you won't have access to HttpRuntime or HttpContect even though there is a namespace for System.Web.

After you do so, you'll have access to:

```
 System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache
```

and could use

```
 HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(
                                    CacheKey,
                                    CacheValue,
                                    null,
                                    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(CacheDuration),
                                    Cache.NoSlidingExpiration
                                );

 Hashtable table1 = HttpRuntime.Cache[CacheKey] as Hashtable;
 HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(CacheKey);
```

You'll also have access to

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application
```

and could use

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("table1",myHashTable);
 Hashtable table1 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["table1"] as Hashtable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use Static Class.

```
        public static class MyDictionary
   {
       public static Dictionary<string,string> French = new Dictionary<string,string>();

        public static Dictionary<string,string> English=new Dictionary<string,string>();
            public static MyDictionary(){   
          while ( dataReader.Read() ) {
           MyDictionary.English.Add( dataReader["field1"].ToString(),Localization.English(dataReader["field1"]));
           MyDictionary.French.Add( dataReader["field2"].ToString(),Localization.French(dataReader["field2"]));
          } 
        }        
      }
```

Then,  If you wanna get value of a word

```
MyDictionary.English["Car"]; // this'll return a string value. if contains
MyDictionary.French["Car"]; // this'll return a string value. if contains
```

Comment: If you use a static class you don't need to place the reader inside of the Global.asax/Application_Start. You just need to create a static constructor for MyDictionary and load the values there. That way your application won't need to load the data until the first time it is accessed. Keep in mind anything you place in Application_Start has to be run before your application pool cycles up. The more you put in there the longer app start times.

Comment: Hi Splash-X. You are right. I didn't think constructor. Constructur is better idea than Application_Start thanks.